# ProtoBuf-Net err msg - "An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

While Serializing a dynamic object with around 250 properties and approx 20,000 rows I am getting the below error. The same code works fine when the number of properties are around 20. The error occurred at point ***Serializer.Serialize(stream, lst);***

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll

at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.Flush(ProtoWriter writer) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 534
at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.Dispose() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 478
at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoWriter.cs:line 472
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 218
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 201
at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 87
at WcfService1.DynamicWrapper.Serialize(DynamicWrapper lst) in c:\Users\rkohli\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WcfService1\SerializeObject.cs:line 136
at WcfService1.Service1.GetData(String sVisibleColumnList) in c:\Users\rkohli\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WcfService1\Service1.svc.cs:line 22
at SyncInvokeGetData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnContinueAsyncReceive(Object state)
at System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.TraceAndInvoke()
at System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.Invoke()
at System.Runtime.ActionItem.CallbackHelper.InvokeWithoutContext(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

*The below is the code sample.*

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class DynamicWrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public List<DictWrapper> Items { get; set; }

    public DynamicWrapper()
    {
        Items = new List<DictWrapper>();
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(DynamicWrapper lst)
    {
        byte[] msgOut;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, lst);
            msgOut = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return msgOut;
    }

    public static DynamicWrapper Deserialize(byte[] message)
    {
        DynamicWrapper msgOut;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(message))
        {
            msgOut = Serializer.Deserialize<DynamicWrapper>(stream);
        }

        return msgOut;
    }
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class DictWrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public Dictionary<string, string > Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DictWrapper()
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So how much data are you trying to read? (What are the types of the properties?) It sounds like you've got 5 million property values - if each value is a long string, I can understand why you could be running out of memory...

Comment: Yes? You are loading 250 x 20,000 items in memory? Why?

Comment: I'm not at a PC - but can you try adding (to the attribute on the list): DataFormat = DataFormat.Group ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I added the attribute as per your recommendation. But still no luck. Now the error message and desc changed. I have updated that above. Just FYI without using the Protobuf-net my existing application is working fine. Even it can transfer more data than the sample which I am trying. So definitely there is some attribute settings which I am missing. Please let me know?

Comment: @Ram I'll have to look at a PC

Comment: @JonSkeet I am dynamically adding the properties. The sample code is shown above. Ideally it would have been better if I could have used Dictionary<string, object > but since it's not supported in Protobuf I am using Dictionary<string, string >.

Comment: Thx @MarcGravell. Will be waiting for an update. Also let me know incase you want me to share the sample application so that the error can be replicated.

Comment: @MarcGravell Did you get a chance to look into this? It will be great if you can give your insight in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magic going on here. Based on the code, and a working project sent separately - the data for that is simply: big. 120446305 bytes, to be precise (based on the sample data). The main problem here is that you are using string property names, and duplicating them over and over and over and over and over. Now, protobuf-net can support string caching and re-use, but it doesn't do it by default - and there's no easy way to apply it to `Dictionary<string,string>`. But frankly, before I go figuring out crazy ways of making it work in this case (which would, by necessity, be a breaking change) I must first point out that this *simply isn't a good fit for protobuf*. Protobuf doesn't offer a "always smaller" guarantee: it offers to do a good job *for typical scenarios*, i.e. where your schema is known up-front and is predictable. Everything this one particular scenario **is not**.

Indeed, in the example given, it is loading data from a `DataSet` - which notably is only 284MB in the original data. Your use of protobuf-net here, for a scenario which is *isn't aimed at*, has resulted in a 4× growth in size.

Frankly, you'd have done better to send the original `DataSet` payload. Or even better:  switch the data-set to binary mode and send that, (162 MB).

```
using (var file = File.Create("binary-ds"))
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(file, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
}
```

Or better yet - switch it to binary mode *and run it through gzip*, for a sum total of 15MB:

```
using (var file = File.Create("binary-ds"))
using (var gzip = new GZipStream(file, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(gzip, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
}
```

If I re-wrote your example using regular POCO/DTO classes and ran *that* through protobuf-net, I suspect the result would be similar (but without all the overhead of `DataTable` here), but there is not going to be a simple way of changing your scenario to play nicely with protobuf-net without having to change the data layout. And if you need to change the data layout - the above is a lot easier.